# Difficulties using message.author to identify who sent a message with Python using the Discord API

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've written some code that is supposed to append every new message it gets from a dm FROM A SPECIFIC USER into a file (using discord). I've written the bulk of it but im not sure about how to do the from a specific user part.

It's possible the reason it isn't working is some other flaw in my code, but I would love to fix this

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.type == "dm":
        if message.author == "MYUSERNAME#MYDISCRIMINATOR":
            print("New message")
            with open('outputmeta.txt', 'a+') as the_file:
                async for log in client.logs_from(message.channel, limit=1000):
                      stringTime = log.timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
                      try:
                          author = log.author
                      except:
                          author = 'invalid'
                      message = str(log.content.encode("utf-8"))[2:-1]

                      template = '[{stringTime}] <{author}> {message}\n'
                      try:
                          the_file.write(template.format(stringTime=stringTime, author=author, message=message))
                      except:
                          author = log.author.discriminator
                          the_file.write(template.format(stringTime=stringTime, author=author, message=message))
                      print(template.format(stringTime=stringTime, author=author, message=message)[:-1])
client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`User.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.id) attribute to identify specific users.  The name/discriminator pair isn't guaranteed to be unique.

```
if message.author.id == 12345:
    ...
```

You can add a `print(message.author.id)` to the top of the event and then send a message to get your own id, or if you're the owner of the bot you can use the [`Client.application_info`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.application_info) coroutine to get your own info:

```
app_info = await client.application_info()
if message.author.id == app_info.owner.id:
    ...
```